# Google App Engine for Businesses Source License

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, licensing

I believe I read that if you wanted to use Google's App Engine, your application needed to be open source. With the recent announcement of App Engine for Business, does the same rule apply? I would like to host an application on this particular platform but have no interest in releasing the code initially (down the road, potentially).

Comment: *Needs* to be open source? I don't think that is true. Any sources?

Comment: To use the Google Code Repository, your code needs to be open source which is probably the root of your misconception.

Comment: No it does not (@jacksonemg). As MSW said, you probably got confused with Google Code.

Comment: There lies the root of my misconception. Thanks for the quick responses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I never heard of this requirement. I know many companies are already deploying proprietary applications on GAE.

The **[App Engine for Business](http://code.google.com/intl/fr/appengine/business/)** thing is, to me, just marketing. It was already possible to build proprietary/business applications on GAE, but they are now offering a number of additional services, useful for business users, and called it **App Engine for Business** for the announcement/marketing effect.

I think you might have confused Google App Engine with [Google Code](http://code.google.com/hosting/). Currently, Google Code only hosts open source projects.

Comment: The main reason App Engine for Business looks interesting at the moment (at least to me) is the fact that they support https on your domain: http://code.google.com/appengine/business/#features. I wish this would get added to the traditional App Engine already.